# Plsql procedure for loop update

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two column `A` and `B` and column `A` has n number of records and I want to update column `B` as `Ud1`, `Ud2`.....by taking a chunk of 2 rows at a time and updating the corresponding `B` column.

```
A  B
1  Ud1
2  Ud1
3  Ud2
4  Ud2
5  Ud3
6  Ud3
.
.
.
```

How can it be done in a procedure by keeping the rows of a in a loop?

Comment: please make a little effort to properly format your text in a more readeable way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in pure SQL with an `UPDATE` statement with:

```
UPDATE <table>
   SET b = TRUNC((a+1)/2);
```

If you must use a procedure then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE update_2rows
IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE <table>
      SET b = TRUNC((a+1)/2);
   --
   COMMIT; -- Optional, you may want to commit here...
END update_2rows;
/
```

Hope it helps!